# Solidity on Remix IDE Error: types/values length mismatch

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

This is my very first question on here, hope someone can assist me.

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
    pragma solidity 0.8.13;
    
    contract VaultContract {
        struct Vault {
            address creator;
            string name;
            address[] users;
            uint256 amount;
        }
    
        uint256 totalVaults;
        mapping(uint256 => Vault) public vaults;
        mapping(address => uint256) public balance;
    
        event VaultDistrubtion(uint256 vaultId, uint256 amount);
    
        function createVault(
            string memory name,
            address[] memory users,
            uint256 initialAmount
        ) public returns (uint256 vaultId) {
            Vault storage vault = vaults[totalVaults];
            vault.creator = msg.sender;
            vault.name = name;
            vault.users = users;
            vault.amount = initialAmount;
            totalVaults += 1;
            return totalVaults - 1;
        }
    
        function addAmount(uint256 vaultId, uint256 amount) public {
            Vault storage vault = vaults[vaultId];
            require(msg.sender == vault.creator, "Not vault owner");
            vault.amount = amount;
        }
    
        function distribute(uint256 vaultId) public {
            Vault storage vault = vaults[vaultId];
            uint256 amountPerUser = vault.amount / vault.users.length;
            if (vault.amount != 0) {
                for (uint8 i; i < vault.users.length; i++) {
                    vault.amount -= amountPerUser;
                    balance[vault.users[i]] = amountPerUser;
                }
            }
            else {
                revert("No Funds Available");
            }
            emit VaultDistrubtion(vaultId, amountPerUser * vault.users.length);
        }
    }
```

Once I deploy the contract on the JVM, I enter information into the **createVault()** function call *(Vault1, 0x03C6FcED478cBbC9a4FAB34eF9f40767739D1Ff7, 0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c, 500).* - Just for a YouTube tutorial I'm trying to follow.

It throws an error when I try and transact, here is the error:

*`transact to VaultContract.createVault errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":3,"values":4}, value={"types":["string","address[]","uint256"],"values":["Vault1","",", 0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c","500"]}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)`*

I have tried without quotes and double quotes from the **createVault()** arguments, it throws another error, here is the error message:

```
 *transact to VaultContract.createVault errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: expected array value (argument=null, value="0x03C6FcED478cBbC9a4FAB34eF9f40767739D1Ff7, 0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.5.0)*
```

I have tried to format the question as good as I can for anyone, who is able to help in any way.

I'm following a Youtube tutorial and I might be missing something.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this part in your error message:

```
Error: types/values length mismatch (count={"types":3,"values":4}
```

Reading this tells you that you have 3 types (3 expected parameters), but 4 values are being used. This is because you aren't passing your `users` as an array, instead you're passing them as individual address parameters. You need to change your call to `createVault` from

```
(Vault1, 0x03C6FcED478cBbC9a4FAB34eF9f40767739D1Ff7, 0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c, 500)
```

to

```
(Vault1, [0x03C6FcED478cBbC9a4FAB34eF9f40767739D1Ff7, 0xCA35b7d915458EF540aDe6068dFe2F44E8fa733c], 500)
```

Comment: Cheers for that :) The other issue I did have after I fixed the **createVault()** call, was that I didn't know about adding double quotes after the array bracket (e.g. ["address1", "address2"] for each address.)  Thanks again!